# Как изменять размер картинки заднего фона под разрешения экрана? CSS

Tags: css, css3

Имеется такая проблема, имею картинку с разрешением около 3200x3200px экран соответственно такое разрешение не поддерживает и просто оставляет все. Соответственно вопрос такой, как изменять размер картинки так, чтобы она была размером с который будет равен разрешению экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=1024&d=identicon&r=PG);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` делает фон обложкой
`max-width: 100%;` растягивает блок по ширине, с сохранением пропорций при условии `height: auto;`

Comment: Все бы хорошо, только высоту он не выставляет почему то.